# Can't login to Facebook using SDK if Native Facebook app is installed

Tags: android, facebook

I have been integrated Facbook SDK in my app and all works, before i published it in Play store. When i published the app it no longer login to Facebook if there is Facebook app installed.

The error is:

```
com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Key hash xxxxxxxxxxxxx does not match any stored key hashes.
```

But i saved this new key hash and the old one(debug version) in to my Facebook app settings.

This is happening only when there is installed Facebook app in the device, if there is not i haven't this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. Facebook showing wrong key-hash in Error Stack trace.

Facebook somehow replacing characters. For my case: i changed '-' to '+' and added '=' at the end of the key and its work for me.

For 100% safety use this code in onCreate() to generate your key-hash.

```
    private void generateHashKey() {
    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "your.package.name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            System.out.println("KeyHash:" + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
}
```